# В какой библиотеке находятся все изначальные функции python

Tags: python, python-3.x

В Python есть изначальный набор функций. Например, такие как print, if и прочее.
Так же при открытии самого интерплетатора или скрипта python автоматически импортируются некоторые модули.
Вопрос: Есть ли в этих модулях такой модуль, который отвечает за начальные функции и где его найти (в файле)?

Comment: Это стандартная сборка пайтона, то есть то, что идёт от разработчиков языка. Все свои библиотеки вы можите найти в установленной папке питона С/path_to_python/Python/Lib/site-packages сдесь будут все библиотеки которые увы установили через pip и дефолтные. А уже в самой документации пайтона, вы можете найти где та или иная интересующая Вас функция находится

Comment: if - не функция, а конструкция языка. Отдельной от самого интерпретатора у него нет, да и реализовать его через какую-то функцию не получится. Исходный код интерпретатора можно посмотреть здесь: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Python. print, input и др. - встроенные функции языка, они реализованы на языке Си, и встроены в интерпретатор. Реализацию встроенных функций можно посмотреть в этом файле: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c

Comment: скажи, зачем тебе это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
help('if')

> The "if" statement
```

`if` - это вообще не функция, это специальная конструкция языка `Python`.

```
help(print)

> Help on built-in function print in module builtins
```

А вот `print` - это *встроенная* функция, подгружаемая автоматически из модуля `builtins`. Можно даже вручную этот импорт повторить:

```
from builtins import print
```

Кстати, `print` стал функцией только в `Python 3`, а в `Python 2` он был просто ключевым словом и вызывался без скобок.

Answer (score 0):

Есть [репозиторий](https://github.com/python) на GitHub. Там можно посмотреть исходный код всего языка python. Проблема лишь в том что большинство встроенных функций давно написаны на языке *С* (Си).
Так же некоторые IDE дают возможность заглянуть в builtins.py, но там лишь определение функций с аргументами и их типами. Например VSCode показывает это так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]